# Split commits into two branches

Tags: git, git-log

I am on a branch named `feature-1`. I run `git log`, which shows me a bunch of commits:

```
commit <HASH-1>
…
commit <HASH-2>
…
commit <HASH-3>
…
commit <HASH-4>
…
```

Now I want `commit <Hash-3>` and *older* commits to be on `feature-1` branch, whereas `commit <HASH-2>` and *newer* commits to be on a new branch named *feature-2*. How can I do that?

Comment: "Commits", not ["commitments"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Commitments_(film)).

Answer (score 9):

This is a great use case for the *interactive rebase* feature.

First create the new `feature-2` branch on the same commit as your current `HEAD` (which points to `feature-1`) by running `git branch feature-2`.

Now run `git rebase -i origin/master`. This will open your `$EDITOR` with something like this:

```
pick 3182a77e Commit 1
pick 6f717613 Commit 2
pick f30c1e92 Commit 3
pick b1c13f14 Commit 4
```

Remove the first two lines and save the file. Now git will recreate the commits so that `feature-1` only contains the commits you want.

Now run `git checkout feature-2` and then again `git rebase -i origin/master`. You will again see all 4 commits, but this time keep only the ones you want in `feature-2`. Save the file again and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the commit that you want to be under your new branch and then create branch from this point.

```
git log --oneline ...

commit <HASH-1>
commit <HASH-2>
commit <HASH-3>
commit <HASH-4>


git checkout -b feature-1 <HASH-3> 
git checkout -b feature-2 <HASH-2> 

and so on,
```

You simply checkout any commit you want (any point in your history) and then you create branch at this point

---

#### How to create branches?

Branches can be created in several ways:

**Create branch from the current commit**

- By creating branch ant not checking them out
  `git branch < branch_name>`
- By creating and switching to a new branch

  ```
  git checkout -b <branch_name>
  git checkout -t <branch_name>
  ```

The default SHA-1 if not specified is the ***HEAD***

**Create branch from selected commit**

By adding sha-1 to the checkout command you **"set"** the commit that your branch will be created from.

```
    git checkout -b <branch_name> <sha-1>
    git checkout -t <branch_name> <sha-1>
```

Comment: what is `-t` in `git checkout -t` ?

Comment: -t = When creating a new branch, set up "upstream" configuration (track)